# Decorator Design Pattern in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, inheritance, anonymous-class

I'm designing of a project I have to do. For that, I have thought to use decorator design pattern. However, I have to adjust my design to the existing implementation of the project. Then, I can't keep completely the decorator design pattern.

The project has an abstract base class (called A) and a set of sub-class (called A1, A2, A3, A4, etc.). I can't modify the code of these classes.

Then, I have to add extra funcionality to these classes. For that, I create an abstract class  (called B) that use to class A (Decorator). I also create concrete decorators that use to classes A1,A2,A3,A4,...

NOTE: As you see, I don't use any interface because the class A doesn't use any interface and I can't modify this code.

But I see some issues in this design:

1) Classes B1,B2,B3,B4,... have to add all methods of classes A1,A2,A3,A4,... for calling to methods of classes A1,A2,A3,A4... For example, in class B1:

```
    class B1 {
      public A1 objectA1;

      B1() {
          objectA1 = new A1();
      }

      public void add(int value) {
          objectA1.add(value);
          // extra funcionality
      } 
    }
```

It can be a problem because if other developers modify the code of classes A,A1,A2,A3,A4,... they also need to modify the code of B,B1,B2,B3,B4,...
I WANT TO PREVENT THAT.

2) Moreover, classes A,A1,A2,A3,A4 have protected methods that only can be accessed from the own class or sub-classes. As I need to access to these methods, I can't use the decorator design pattern.

SECOND ALTERNATIVE

I could extend the classes A1,A2,A3,A4 with B1,B2,B3,B4. For example:

```
    class B1 extends A1 {

      B1() {
          objectA1 = new A1();
      }

      public void add(int value) {
          super.add(value);
          // extra funcionality
      } 
    }
```

Of this way, I solve the second problem and avoid to override all methods of A1, overriding only necessary methods. Even so, each time a sub-class of A is created, it's necessary to create the corresponding class B. 
I WANT TO PREVENT THAT because it only is necessary that class B (B1,B2,...) override a method of class A (A1,A2,...).

THIRD ALTERNATIVE

Then, I thought that I could consider to class B (B1,B2,...) as a wrapper of class A (A1,A2,...). Of this way, a instance of B will be created as next:

```
    new BMaker.get(A1, params_of_constructor_A1)
    new BMaker.get(A2, params_of_constructor_A2)
    new BMaker.get(A3, params_of_constructor_A3)
    new BMaker.get(A4, params_of_constructor_A4) or 
    ...
    new BMaker.get(AN, params_of_constructor_AN)
```

where BMaker.get is a static method.

```
    public static <T extends A> A get (T objectA, params ) {
        // return anonymous class (*1)
    }
```

My question is if it's possible to implement an anonymous class that inherit of A1, A2, ...
Each call to BMaker.get() should be created a different anonymous class deppending on if the first parameter of BMaker.get() is A1,A2,A3,...

Really, I don't know if it's possible to do this or is there another better way.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You are confusing *decorator* with *delegator*. You tried delegator, but *want* decorator. Search wikipedia for the terms.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to the first issue:

1. Either put an interface I on A so your decorators/delegates can implement same interface, or
2. Create an interface I (equivalent to A's api) and a wrapper class AW which wraps A and implements I by passing all calls straight onto it.

Convert your client code to use I rather than A, and you can then happily proceed to build decorators/ or delegates using the new interface having "wrapped up" the old crunk in AW.

The one notable issue that arises is that some styles of code using A (IdentityHashMaps, persistence) may want a reference to the "underlying" A. If that comes up, you can put a method in the interface `getUnderlyingA()`. Try and avoid using that too much, since it obviously bypasses all decoration.

---

Second issue:  decorating subtypes.

The question here is whether the subtypes need to be exposed as different decorator types -- or whether one uniform decorator can be exposed, that (maybe, if necessary) is internally aware of the type-system of the A subtypes that it can wrap.

If the subtypes are well-known & stable, you can implement a "handle style" api in the interface. For example, for file-system entities, you would present a handle of a single type but offer `isFile()`, `isDirectory()`, `isDevice()`, `isDrive()`, `isRaw()` etc methods for *interrogating* the type. A `listFiles()` method could be available to *use* the directory subtype.

My question is why you need external access (from the decorator) to protected methods? If you do, **those methods should be public** and the original design is broken/insufficiently extensible.

Maybe you can create a static helper class in the same package (if not changing the A class itself) that will give you proper access to this legacy crunk from your decorator.

---

There's a certain point here, where doing your job properly does sometimes involve working with & potentially upgrading legacy code. If there isn't an efficient & maintainable design alternative, that shouldn't be a total sticking point. Doubling up the type-system (creating two parallel heirarchies) is definitely not what you should be doing.

If there isn't a good way to do this, you should work on something else (a different feature/requirement) rather than making the codebase even worse.